# How to disable all notifications in MS Office 2008, Entourage?

Tags: ms-office

The subject says it all, but for further explanation, MS Office has this (what I consider annoying feature) of notifying me of pretty much anything that happens in Entourage—emails, calendar events, and the like. This is similar to the new "My Day" feature but the notifications pop-up in the lower-right corner of the screen.

I use one particular installation for developing scripts and I don't need to notifications. I don't even need Entourage, for that matter, but the install is managed by my IT department, not me. I've looked through everything I can think of to turn off all of the notifications, and the only way I have managed to *completely* stop them is to zip up the Entourage application. But that results in every *other* application in the Office suite to state on start up that there is a problem with the Office database (but then they work normally otherwise) and the update application won't allow updates to happen because it can't find the correct installation.

Does anyone know of a way to *completely* turn off all the little pop-up notifications that Entourage seems to foist on me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the Microsoft Database daemon from login and do not open Entourage you should receive no notifications.

Comment: Every time I remove the daemon it gets put back into place, but that was in 2004. I'll give that a try.

Comment: I'm still haven't gotten around to fixing the damage I had done to my Office install trying o get around this, but I didn't want to leave this hanging, and this is a completely logical answer.