# How do I disable Microsoft Outlook 2010 calendar notifications?

Tags: ms-office, preferences

I use "Mail" as my default mail client and "iCal" as my default calendar. However I have to use outlook when sending emails to work because their outlook for windows clients don't support inlining and display my images as attachments.

The only problem with this is that my calendar notifications appear twice, once for iCal and once for Outlook, even when outlook is closed. I could disable outlook mail notifications but not calendar ones, any ideas?

Comment: You might want to take a look at my question about version 2008: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4156/how-to-disable-all-notifications-in-ms-office-2008-entourage Office versions can vary enough that I don't think this is a dupe, but it is relevant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

Go to the menu item Outlook -> Turn Off Office Reminders